# How do I deal with empty user input in a Bash script?

Tags: string, bash

When the script asks me for input, I get an error if I just press Return without typing in anything. How do I fix this?

Here's the script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

   SUM=0
   NUM=0

   while true
   do echo -n "Pruefungspunkte eingeben ('q' zum Beenden): "
      read SCORE
      if test "$SCORE" == "q"
      then echo "Durchschnittspunktzahl: $AVERAGE."
           break
      else SUM=`expr $SUM + $SCORE`
           NUM=`expr $NUM + 1`
           AVERAGE=`expr $SUM / $NUM`
      fi
   done
```

Comment: What error in particular?

Comment: I can't tell, someone asked me to fix this

Comment: @user2488736 You could at least copy the content into a file, execute the use case you described and tell us which error is generated.

Comment: Aha, someone asked you to fix it, then you asked someone else and so on. I bet that someone is not an original author of question either.

Comment: Whats wrong with asking someone for help if you can't find a solution, I'm a total newb sry

Comment: I'll tell you what's wrong - you don't have all the information we may need to answer.

Answer (score 3):

How about using good bash practices?

```
#!/bin/bash

sum=0
num=0

while true; do
   read -erp "Pruefungspunkte eingeben ('q' zum Beenden): " score
   if [[ $score = q ]]; then
      echo "Durchschnittspunktzahl: $average."
      break
   elif [[ $score =~ ^-?[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then
      ((sum+=10#$score))
      ((++num))
      ((average=sum/num))
   else
      echo "Bad number"
   fi
done
```

Good practice:

- don't use capitalized variable names
- use the `[[` builtin instead of the `test` builtin
- don't use backticks, use `((` to invoke shell arithmetic
- to make sure the user inputs a number, check that a number was really entered. The line

  ```
  elif [[ $score =~ ^-?[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then
  ```

  just does that (see regular expressions). Incidentally it completely solves your original problem, since an empty input will not pass through this test
- to prevent problems if a user enters `09` instead of `9`, force bash to interpret the input in radix `10`. That's why I'm using `(10#$score)` instead of just `score`.
- Use `read` with the `-p` (prompt) option, instead of the clumsy combo `echo -n` / `read`

This version is much more robust and well-written than yours. Yet, it still has problems:

- will break if user needs large numbers
- as shell arithmetic is used, only integers can be used. Moreover, the average given by this program is rounded: if you want the average of `1` and `2` you'll have `1`.

To fix both problems, you'll probably want to use `bc` or `dc`. But that will be the purpose of another question. Or not.

Comment: Please, quote the variable `"$score"`. If user's input has a space, you will fail on `[[ $score ... ]]` expansion.

Comment: @bartimar, according to [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) (and personal experience), "word splitting ... are not performed on the words between the ‘[[’ and ‘]]’ ..."

Comment: @bartimar thanks for your comment. `$score` need not be quoted inside `[[` (see doubleDown's comment above). That's one reason why I mentioned using `[[` instead of `test` (see good practice point 2). And thanks for downvoting.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry... I lived in a lie! I think it will expand first and the space will be a problem. My apologies for the down, can you edit it so i can up? :/

Answer (score 1):

Initialise `$SCORE` beforehand or handle empty input like you do in `q` case.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[ -z "$SCORE" ]] && echo "\$SCORE is zero, e.g. \"\""
```

This will test if the variable SCORE is empty string.

You should also set `AVERAGE=0` at the beginning.